# htaccess rewrite secondary domain to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, subdomain, document-root

I have a main domain "www.main.com" with subdomain "subdomain.main.com"

the subdomain is located in the folder `/htdocs/subdomain/` and the main domain is a symbolic link to the `/htdocs/www/` (which also serves www.main.com)

Now I have registered a new domain name, "newname.com" which I have connected to my hosting account. Now I am trying to determine the contents of `/htdocs/.htaccess` for rewriting incoming requests to subdomain.main.com.

To be clear, I do not want to *redirect*. I want `www.newname.com/anything` to be *rewritten* to `subdomain.main.com/anything`, while the user keeps on navigating `newname.com`.
I fear there is a catch with circular rewrites?

What should my `.htaccess` look like?

My document root is /htdocs and the subdomain and the new domain are on the same ip address.

Comment: Where is the document root for "newname.com"?

Comment: thats /htdocs (i updated the post)

Comment: Is there a cpanel or something similar through your hosting service that you can set your document root for newname.com to `/htdocs/subdomain/`? Or is there another reason you need it to be `/htdocs`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make **sure** your DNS is properly setup i.e. `ping www.newname.com` goes to the same server (= same IP) than `ping subdomain.main.com`.

Then your vhost should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@papdevis.fr
    DocumentRoot "/home/subdomain"

    ServerName subdomain.main.com
    ServerAlias www.newname.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Then everything should work transparently. It's all about vhosts. I don't know with htaccess, sorry.

Comment: i dont have permission to create a vhost file

Comment: it was in fact easy, i created a symbolic link to my new domain (http://www.primary.com/secondary) (which points to secondary.primary.com) and I rewrite all queries to www.secondary.com to that. Totally untransparent, just how I wanted it. It was just a bit fighting with drupal to make sure it let me take control of a tiny part of my main domain :)

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact easy, i created a **symbolic link** to my new domain (primary.com/secondary) which links to the folder which also serves secondary.primary.com and I rewrite all queries to www.secondary.com to that symbolic link. Totally untransparent, just how I wanted it. It was just a bit fighting with drupal before it let me take control of a tiny part of my main domain :)

The main .htaccess is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondary.com [NC] 
RewriteCond $1 !^secondary/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /secondary/$1
```

and i redirect all secondary.com to www.secondary.com in my rewrite base with this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondary.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secondary.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```